# New-SPContentDatabase : String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: 2013, content-database

When creating new database manually in PowerShell using command

```
New-SPContentDatabase -Name $ContentDatabase -WebApplication $WebApplicationName
```

it works fine, but *recently* it has started to fail when it is run as part of nightly build. If I run the exact same scripts manually on the same farm, I get no errors. Error it gives is:

```
2015-12-08T07:51:03.8157500Z ##[error]New-SPContentDatabase : String or binary data would be truncated.     
2015-12-08T07:51:03.8157500Z ##[error]The statement has been terminated.     
2015-12-08T07:51:03.8157500Z ##[error]At E:\Builds\Plaza for SharePoint\Scripts\50_CreateModuleSiteCollections.ps1:36 char:9     
2015-12-08T07:51:03.8157500Z ##[error]+         New-SPContentDatabase -Name $ContentDatabase -WebApplication $WebApplica ...     
2015-12-08T07:51:03.8157500Z ##[error]+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~     
2015-12-08T07:51:03.8157500Z ##[error]    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...ContentDatabase:SPCmdletNewContentDatabase) [New-SPConte      
2015-12-08T07:51:03.8157500Z ##[error]   ntDatabase], SqlException     
2015-12-08T07:51:03.8157500Z ##[error]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewContentDatabase
```

In ULS logs it says things like:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated.  The statement has been terminated.

Unknown SQL Exception 8152 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.  String or binary data would be truncated.  The statement has been terminated.

Exception occured during acquiring a server lock. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated.  The statement has been terminated.
```

I have all the recent Windows Updates installed to SQL and SharePoint.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `stsadm.exe` instead of `New-SPContentDatabase`

I had a similar issue and it worked for me.

Example:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\BIN\STSADM.EXE' -o addcontentdb -databasename $dbName -url $webAppUrl
```

Ref:
http://blog.jussipalo.com/2016/02/sharepoint-new-spcontentdatabase-in.html